# Push array into multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays first is like below.

> First Array

```
Array
(
 [0] => images.jpg
 [1] => iamge12.png
)
```

> Second Array

```
  Array
  (
 [0] => Array
    (
        [entity_id] => 2
        [website_id] => 1
        [gender] => 0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [entity_id] => 24
        [website_id] => 1
        [gender] => 1
    )
    )
```

Would like to push **First Array** into **Second Array**.

So that my second array will looks like

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [entity_id] => 2
        [website_id] => 1
        [gender] => 0|
        [image] => images.jpg
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [entity_id] => 3
        [website_id] => 1
        [gender] => 1|
        [image] => iamge12.png
    )
)
```

> My Code.

```
  print_r($imageArr); // First Array
  print_r($items->getData()); // Second Array

    array_push($imageArr,$items->getData());
```

Note : First array key and second array key has to be same.

I tried with **Array Push** but it didn't work at all.

Comment: And show your code with `array_push`

Comment: You Can use 'array_merge();' of function

Comment: Check my edit and how i want array to looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($array1 as $key => $value){
    if(array_key_exists($key, $array2)){
        $array2[$key]['image']= $value;
    }
}
```

this solves your problem

Comment: @DomenikReitzner yeah, that's correct too, but I saw this line from OP: `First array key and second array key has to be same.` It suggests that it should insert image when there already is item for given key in array2

Comment: Yes @stetoc. I would still use the check if array_key_exists. But after that you don't have to use `$array2[$key][] = ['image' => $value]`. That is what I meant

Comment: @DomenikReitzner yeah, that's true, I missed it when writing code, edited

Comment: @stetoc awesome 

Comment: @TBS Mage if this answer did'nt work then why you marked it as "correct" ?

Comment: @AbdullahShoaib, There's typo on my side. Code is correct that'w why...

Comment: @TBS Mage Ohh. That's why somebody said "Think before Ink".

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($second as $key => $value) {
    $result[] = array_merge($value,[ 'image'=> $first[$key] ]);
}
```